# Where can I buy game sprites and tiles?

Tags: graphics, tiles, vector, sprite

Yes, I'd prefer to buy them instead of using "free" or "free" with some kind of weird license. Tried Google, but no luck and my fav RF graphics sites don't have any... :(

Comment: What genre, size and style are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're unlikely to find sets of tiles that are simultaneously online, exactly meet your needs and are purchasable for a fee.

I'd suggest going to one of the freelance graphics / design sites e.g. [99 designs](http://99designs.com/) and get the work done for a small commission. Depending on your game you will probably have custom requirements anyway, so getting custom tiles created is probably the best bet. This is how I'm planning to source the graphics and artwork for my next game.

Alternatively, you'd be surprised by how many good "free" tile sets you can find. But then you will be forced to stick to the graphic style and theme of the free tileset, and run the risk of looking very similar to other games using the same tileset.

Answer (score 0):

You could pay someone to create them, perhaps at a site like [vWorker/Rent A Coder](http://www.vworker.com/RentACoder/DotNet/default.aspx).

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to browse already created stuff and just buy w/e is good for my projects. Something like graphicriver/iStock etc...